Wording a variadic concept to get clangd autocomplete
I have the following concept:
template<typename T, typename MsgType>
concept CanSend = requires(T obj)
{
  {obj.send(std::declval<MsgType>())} -> std::same_as<void>;
};

template<typename Handler, typename... MessageTypes>
concept HandlerConcept = (CanSend<Handler, MessageTypes> && ...); 

I would like to re-write this to an equivalent concept C such that clangd is able to figure out that C has a send method. Right now, if I write:
template<HandlerConcept<int> HandlerT>
void foo(HandlerT obj)
{
   obj.send(5);
}

My autocomplete is not able to figure out that obj has this send method. Comparatively, clangd is able to figure this out in the following snippet that obj has a method send()...
template<CanSend<int> T>
void foo(T obj)
{
}


Can it figure it out when you write template<CanSend<int> HandlerT>? What about when you do template<typename T> requires HandlerConcept<T, int>? Your two examples aren't equivalent, so please make sure you aren't comparing apples to oranges here.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica good idea - updated the example to be consistent and unfortunately using requires in our derived concept, HandlerConcept, does not change anything.

Thank you. A small consolation is that Clangd is likely to improve for C++26, since constraint normalization was extended with coverage of fold expressions https://wg21.link/P2963R3 - I suspect Clangd's behavior is tied to that.

Unrelated: you can probably get rid of the std::declval by specifying a second parameter to the requires clause, like requires(T obj, MsgType msg).

Clangd's concept-based auto-completion is very primitive at this stage. There was some initial work done on it in https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/261, and nothing further since then, so whatever simple cases were handled in that patch is what currently works.
I would encourage you file clangd issues about cases that do not work (like the one in your question), to inform / focus any potential future work in this area.
